# Nested Tabs with Repeater - Advance Custom Fields Wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, bootstrap-tabs

I want to make some tabs with Wordpress Using the Advance Custom Field Plug-in with the Repeater Add-On.

This is my actual code:

```
<?php

if( have_rows('menu_sections') ): ?>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="" role="tablist">
        <?php $i=0; while ( have_rows('menu_sections') ) : the_row(); ?>
            <?php
            $string = sanitize_title( get_sub_field('section_title') );
            ?>
            <li role="presentation" <?php if ($i==0) { ?>class="active"<?php } ?>  >
                <a  role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><?php the_sub_field('section_title'); ?></a>
            </li>
        <?php $i++; endwhile; ?>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
        <?php $i=0; while ( have_rows('menu_sections') ) : the_row(); ?>
            <?php
            $string = sanitize_title( get_sub_field('section_title') );
            ?>
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane text-left fade <?php if ($i==0) { ?>in active<?php } ?>" id="<?php echo $string; ?>">
                <?php
                while (have_rows('section_items')) {
                    the_row();
                    // Display each item as a list
                    ?>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="list-unstyled"><?php the_sub_field('dish_name'); ?></li>
                        <li class="list-unstyled"><?php the_sub_field('dish_description'); ?></li>
                        <li class="list-unstyled"><?php the_sub_field('dish_price'); ?></li>
                    </ul>
                    <?php
                } // end while have rows section_items
                ?>
            </div>
        <?php $i++; endwhile; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This Actual code displays this:

[image]

Now if i select another tab it won't change the card info as you can see in the next image:

[image]

Im using a Bootstrap Tabs with a CDN

This is what the Gooogle console display:
[image]

So I tried many different ways but no success at all.

I do know how to make them without a nested repeater, and with this case I don't know why it dosen't work. I read some other posts but no having much success either. So I think that if it dosen't show is something with css??

I will appreaciate the help.
Regards!

Comment: you need to create individual repeater field in every single tab(tab vise repeater field) and than add value to that field and then display that field.

Comment: @Krishnathakor I kinda get what your saying. But thanks. I think ive donde that. I'll try and see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing

```
<li role="presentation" <?php if ($i==0) { ?>class="active"<?php } ?>  >
  <a  role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><?php the_sub_field('section_title'); ?></a>
</li>
```

to

```
<li role="presentation" <?php if ($i==0) { ?>class="active"<?php } ?>  >
  <a  role="tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php the_sub_field('section_title'); ?></a>
</li>
```

and

```
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane text-left fade <?php if ($i==0) { ?>in active<?php } ?>" id="<?php echo $string; ?>">
```

to

```
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane text-left fade <?php if ($i==0) { ?>in active<?php } ?>" id="tab-<?php echo $i; ?>">
```

I hope it will solve the issue. You are assigning a section title as id to tab-pane, which might contain space as well. It's always recommended to use id without spaces.

Comment: People needs people like you. THANKS!!! It worked!!!!!!!!! I can finish my proyect today. You saved my life